# Add title attribute for custom radio buttons based on user selection

Tags: html, css, angular

I've created a custom styled radio buttons. Now i'm struggling to add a title attribute to it.

Basically i wanted to add title text like `Checked/Unchecked` based on the user selection.

How do i do it in Angular 2? Please help

**Note:** I wanted to add title tooltip only of the `Radio Circle` not for the entire text.

```css
.radio-radio-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 6px;
  margin: 10px 0 0;
}

.radio-radio-wrapper input[type='radio'] {
  display: none;
}

.radio-radio-wrapper label:before {
  content: " ";
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 11px;
  border: 2px solid #004c97;
  background-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.radio-radio-wrapper input[type=radio]:checked+span>label:after {
  border-radius: 11px;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 4px;
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  background: #004c97;
}
```

```html
<div _ngcontent-c9="" class="col-lg-12 radioBlock">
  <span _ngcontent-c9="" class="radio-radio-wrapper padding-radio">
            <input _ngcontent-c9="" id="radio1" name="radio" type="radio" ng-reflect-name="radio" ng-reflect-value="Capacity" ng-reflect-model="Capacity" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid">
            <span _ngcontent-c9="" class="radioLabel"><label _ngcontent-c9="" class="custom-control-description" for="radio1">Capacity &amp; Radio 1</label></span>
  </span><span _ngcontent-c9="" class="radio-radio-wrapper padding-radio">
            <input _ngcontent-c9="" id="radio2" name="radio" type="radio" ng-reflect-name="radio" ng-reflect-value="Prod" ng-reflect-model="Capacity" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid">
            <span _ngcontent-c9="" class="radioLabel"><label _ngcontent-c9="" class="custom-control-description" for="radio2">Radio 2</label></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't get it. You add a title attribute by... adding a title attribute. What does all this HTML and CSS have to do with anything? Also the HTML is _complied_ by Angular, this is not source code.

Comment: if user check's on the radio button, title should be `checked` else it should be `Unchecked`

Comment: OK. I do not see any attempt to do this. What exactly are you having problems with?

Comment: `.radio-radio-wrapper input[type=radio]:checked + span > label:hover::before{
    content:'Checked';
    position: absolute;
 }` with this code i can able to added the text on Hover, but i'm not able to style the content text

Comment: i wanted to know whether it can be achieved in Angular without CSS?